# I have an array in Unity. I want to assign an image based on the gameobject's tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

This is in Unity 2018.4.20f LTS. I have a lot of 3d gameobjects that I'm storing in an Array. I have searched around but can't find a way to do it. Right now I have a panel and a bunch of white box images as placeholders. When I pick up an object a white box pops up on my canvas panel.

What I would like to know is there a way to grab an image and display it in place of the white place holder image based on the gameobject's tag? Like if it is tagged hammer and I have a hammer image display that image?

If so could someone point me in the right direction on how I would accomplish this?

Comment: Its not possible to answer this from your description. Please add some code or samples.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a reference to the image in a c sharp script you can change the sprite being rendered with (sprite variable of newImageSprite)

```
imageOne.sprite = newImageSprite;
```

edit if you have an array of gamobjects

```
gameObjectOne.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = newImageSprite;

if (gameObjectOne.tag == "Hammer") {
imageGameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = hammerSprite;
}
```